# Website only shows ip address, not domain name

Tags: dns, ip, domain-name, joomla

I'm trying to set up a website on a home server with joomla. I've managed to set up correct forwarding so it is accessible via my IP address, and I have purchased a domain name from a hosting provider. I set up the DNS settings to point my domain name to my IP address, but any request to the domain name first gets routed to a different IP address, which sends back a 301 response, with my IP as the new target. I then end op on my website with the plain IP address in the address bar.

Now I have very limited experience with DNS, but this seems wrong? In googling for the issue I mostly get results about this being a joomla and/or apache issue and get pointed to various config files, but I don't want to mess those up just yet unless I'm sure the problem doesn't lie anywhere else.

Could what I'm seeing with the 301 redirect be the cause of this issue or is it definitely on the server config side?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you've set up wasn't the DNS record but an HTTP redirect (from a virtual host at your hoster).

If DNS is set correctly, an `nslookup` or `dig` should show an A record resolving the DNS name to the IP of your server. As it is, the A record likely points to the virtual host where your provider redirects the request.